# How to make background of EMF symbol transparent in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, transparency-opacity, emf

I have been sent a collection of PNG and SVG images with which I should symbolize my points in ArcGIS 10.0. Unfortunately ArcGIS 10.0 doesn´t support PNG when symbolizing points, so I have converted them to EMF files. The background transparency of the images are now lost and are displayed black. How can I make the background of these emf images transparent in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Knowledge Base document entitled **[FAQ:  What is the best format to use when inserting logos into a map document while maintaining transparency?](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29254)** which says:

> Logos are usually designed in a vector illustration package such as
>   Adobe Illustrator, and then exported to a pixel-based format. However,
>   exporting the logo as EMF will maintain the vectors and allow resizing
>   in ArcMap without loss of quality. It will display correctly in ArcMap
>   when printed and exported since there is no background to a vector
>   drawing.

If you do not have access to Adobe Illustrator  to create your EMF files then **[Program to create EMF that conserves transparency](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28566/program-to-create-emf-that-conserves-transparency)** may be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks...but i´m still having difficulties. I have a png in Illustrator which has a transparent background. When I export it to emf format it gets given a white background. There is no export properties to set. - But I´m not talking about images like in your link. I am trying to symbolize a point feature classe in ArcGIS

Comment: @RobertBuckley That sounds like your export from Adobe Illustrator is where your transparency is lost.  Since Illustrator is not GIS software I recommend that you pursue that as a separate Question via [**Super User**](http://superuser.com).  Can you also edit your Question here to include your precise steps in more detail, please?