# Text Background objects not overlaying properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

To complete a map of highways, I've needed to create labels with text backgrounds. I'm attempting to recreate a proper County route sign such as this:[image: County Route Sign]

So, I made a text background out of 3 objects: A small blue pentagon, a slightly larger yellow pentagon, and a slightly larger blue pentagon. Then I label it with the number of the route. It comes out looking like this:

[image: Crappy route sign]

You can see how the individual pentagons are not properly centered on one another. I know how to fix this manually. I can just readjust the x and y positions of the individual pieces until they line up properly. What I want to know is what is causing the individual pentagons to come out uncentered from one another. Especially since the same symbol will come out fine in one map, screwed up one way in one map and screwed up another way in another map!

Edit: I am using Maplex label engine.

Comment: added arcgis tag [as you mention maplex]

Comment: try using .emf format for your symbols - related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28566/program-to-create-emf-that-conserves-transparency

Comment: try suggestion of @mapperez by creating the label with nongis software... you can see the difference the firs label is an image, meanwhile the second is dynamic label . It can be seen by their border line, the first one has a raster line the second has a vector line.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The simplest way of getting an .emf file I could figure out (I can't install programs on my computer at work without administrator permissions) was to use the Gravit web portal to export an .svg file of my shields and then use a web-based file converter to turn the .svg into a .emf.

Strangely, when I would export out of Gravit, it would cause the same issue of the pentagons being incorrectly overlaid! It took many iterations to get the object I want, but I only need to get it right once now. There must be something about exporting that I don't understand